# How to create JSON Object Using Java

Tags: java, json

I'm new in JSON and I need help to make a JSON.

I already searching for JSON like this sample, but I can't find any.

```
{
 "data": {
 "Name": "Alex",
 "id": "12345",
 "attributes": {
 "Class" : "12A"
  }
 }
}
```

I don't know how to show `data` and I think with that sample they don't use array, isn't it? From all website I found, I only can make this code like this

```
String message;
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
//data?
json.put("Name", "Alex");
json.put("id","12345");
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
item.put("Class", "12A");

array.put(item);
json.put("attributes", array);
message = json.toString();
System.out.println(message);
```

On this code, I get the result like below, but is it okay if my id name is under attributes?

```
{
"attributes":[
  {
     "Class":"12A"
  }
],
"id":"12345",
"Name":"Alex"
}
```

Comment: "Is it okay..."? OK in what context? You've created valid JSON, but it isn't the same as the JSON object at the start of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest this :

```
JsonObject obj = Json.createObjectBuilder()
    .add("data", Json.createObjectBuilder()
        .add("Name", "Alex")
        .add("id", "12345")
        .add("attributes", Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("Class", "12A")))
    .build();
```